# PHP API returns stale and raw data in the result of ajax call when submit form data to update database table using javascript ajax and php api

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, api

I have a page named products.php where I have two tables "category" and another one is "products". The products in the product table are listed on that page below the category table which shows all the categories and the corresponding products number listed under that category.

I have two functions load_products.php and load_categories.php in javascript which are called every time I refresh the page. So, with the "innerHTML" I set the Html returned by PHP API in the specific div tag.

All the categories and products are listed perfectly as they were being expected.
But the issue is here: when I hit the edit product button to edit the product, only the product table gets updated due to "fetch_products() and fetch_categories()" functions in the javascript ajax success method.

Note: categories table also gets updated but it is giving me stale and raw data in the categories table.

```
async function fetch_categories(){
  const fetch_result = await fetch(`server/load_categories.php`);
  const fetch_res = await fetch_result.json();
  $("#load_categories").html(fetch_res.message);
}
fetch_categories();

async function fetch_products(){
  const result = await fetch(`server/load_products.php`);
  const res = await result.json();
  $("#load_products").html(res.message);
}
fetch_products();


$("#edit_product_form").on("submit",function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
const name = $("#edit_product_name").val();
const tagline = $("#edit_product_tagline").val();
const purchase_price = $("#edit_purchase_price").val();
const sale_price = $("#edit_sale_price").val();
const discount_price = $("#edit_discounted_price").val();
const description = $("#edit_description").val();

function show_error(id) {
  document.querySelector(`${id} .field_message`).style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.querySelector(`${id} .field_message`).style.display = "none";
  }, 10000);
}
let formData = new FormData(this);

if (name == "") {
  show_error("#product_name_feild");
} else if (tagline == "") {
  show_error("#product_tagline_feild");
} else if (parseInt(purchase_price) < 1) {
  alert("Please add valid purchase price");
} else if (discount_price > parseInt(sale_price)) {
  alert("Please add valid discounted price");
} else if (parseInt(sale_price) < 1) {
  alert("Please add valid sale price");
} else if (discount_price < 1) {
  alert("Please add valid discounted price");
} else if (description === "") {
  show_error("#product_description_field");
} else {
  $.ajax({
    url: "server/edit_product.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (response) {
      const res = JSON.parse(response);
      if(res.success){
        $("#edit_product_modal_back").css({"display" : "none"});
        fetch_categories();
      }else if(res.error){
        $("#edit_product_modal_back").css({"display" : "none"});
        alert("Product Could not add due to some server error!");
      }
      fetch_products();
    }
  });
}
});
```

Comment: Define "stale"...what precisely do you expect to have changed in the category data? And since we cannot see what `load_categories.php`, it's likely to be difficult for us to understand what might be going wrong. Please ensure you've provided us with a [mre] of the issue. Also, I'm assuming you've verified that the `fetch()` call to `load_categories.php` definitely succeeds after the Edit form has been submitted?

Comment: You are making a request to edit a product - yet you call `fetch_products` completely independently of whether the response indicated success or not, but instead you are making fetching of the categories dependent on that. Thats a bit weird logic in general, isn't it? Why do you even need to update the display of the categories _at all_ at this point? (I don't see any category related data in what you are validating there, but the form you are serializing might contain more fields, granted.) But at least it should _also_ be dependent on success or failure of the update operation then, no?